# Angular 2, video duration access.

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im trying to get video duration from my videos that i listed in a table. I tried to access it using @ViewChildren and was successful until one part. i get the query list but when i try accessing _results it returns undefined. Later I learned that queryList was private for some reason. Any help will be appreciated

Here is my code:

```
<video id="video1" #video>
<source src = "{{videos.link}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
@ViewChildren('video') video;
ngOnInit: {
Observable.timer(1000,1000).subscribe(() => {
if(this.video && !this.isVideoLogged){
console.log(this.video);
this.isVideoLogged = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `loadedmetadata` event:

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zydF0qry9i9eq0QyluUl?p=preview)

```
<video width="480" controls #video (loadedmetadata)="onMetadata($event, video)"
```

```
  onMetadata(e, video) {
    console.log('metadata: ', e);
    console.log('duration: ', this.duration = video.duration);
  }
```

Comment: how to handle duration acces for more than one video that are viewed with ngFor. Because i get log all the time

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you update the plunker to demonstrate?

Comment: I cant because im calling a private API i will try to explain it here. So i have a list of videos that i get from an API and list it with ngFor when i call the (loadedmetada) function, it calls the function infinitely many times. How can i call it just once get the duration and than stop calling.

Comment: It's probably how you bind `*ngFor` to data. I assume you bind to a method that returns a new array every time it's called which makes `*ngFor` re-render the video elements again and again because every time change detection runs, `*ngFor` re-fetches the array. But that is just a wild guess.

Comment: oh yes I have an observable. timer that calls the api every sec. as there are many changes. Thank you so much you are of a great help!